# Is it possible to determine the height of a video in an IFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, iframe

We are using Buto to host our videos and showing them in a lightbox (FancyBox) on our site via a floating IFrame.

Problem is that the videos are of different heights and widths, and we don't know these dimensions in the simple html pages (no server-side code) that link to the videos, so whatever dimensions we choose for the IFrame are going to be wrong for some of the videos.

I'd like to have some javascript that runs after the Video has loaded and resizes the IFrame to neatly fit around the video.

Is this even possible, given that the Iframe is hosting content from *another domain*? Can anyone recommend an alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post an example of the iframe code perhaps using http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: I made playground on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m2fUE/1/ but cannot get to read iframe contents after load. Maybe somebody else can crack it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you can't access iframe's content if domain, port and protocol don't match with the hosting page ones.

You should use a proxy page ([here an example](http://www.johnchapman.name/aspnet-proxy-page-cross-domain-requests-from-ajax-and-javascript/)), or [accessing Buto via API](http://get.buto.tv/developer/help/) (no JSONP, unfortunately), but you need to run some server-side code for that...

Comment: Thanks - I have installed "Application Request Routing" on our IIS 7.0 server and have enabled the proxy therein, so can now set up a rewrite rule using the rewrite module in IIS, and proxy Buto's XML file into my jQuery and hence set the IFrame size. Thanks for your suggestions :)